# WordPress page is scrolling by itself and begins to shake

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

```js
! function(a, b, c) {
    function d(a, c) {
        var d = b(a);
        d.data(f, this), this._$element = d, this.shares = [], this._init(c), this._render()
    }
    var e = "JSSocials",
        f = e,
        g = function(a, c) {
            return b.isFunction(a) ? a.apply(c, b.makeArray(arguments).slice(2)) : a
        },
        h = /(\.(jpeg|png|gif|bmp|svg)$|^data:image\/(jpeg|png|gif|bmp|svg\+xml);base64)/i,
        i = /(&?[a-zA-Z0-9]+=)?\{([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\}/g,
        j = {
            G: 1e9,
            M: 1e6,
            K: 1e3
        },
        k = {};
    d.prototype = {
        url: "",
        text: "",
        shareIn: "blank",
        showLabel: function(a) {
            return this.showCount === !1 ? a > this.smallScreenWidth : a >= this.largeScreenWidth
        },
        showCount: function(a) {
            return a <= this.smallScreenWidth ? "inside" : !0
        },
        smallScreenWidth: 640,
        largeScreenWidth: 1024,
        resizeTimeout: 200,
        elementClass: "jssocials",
        sharesClass: "jssocials-shares",
        shareClass: "jssocials-share",
        shareButtonClass: "jssocials-share-button",
        shareLinkClass: "jssocials-share-link",
        shareLogoClass: "jssocials-share-logo",
        shareLabelClass: "jssocials-share-label",
        shareLinkCountClass: "jssocials-share-link-count",
        shareCountBoxClass: "jssocials-share-count-box",
        shareCountClass: "jssocials-share-count",
        shareZeroCountClass: "jssocials-share-no-count",
        _init: function(a) {
            this._initDefaults(), b.extend(this, a), this._initShares(), this._attachWindowResizeCallback()
        },
        _initDefaults: function() {
            this.url = a.location.href, this.text = b.trim(b("meta[name=description]").attr("content") || b("title").text())
        },
        _initShares: function() {
            this.shares = b.map(this.shares, b.proxy(function(a) {
                "string" == typeof a && (a = {
                    share: a
                });
                var c = a.share && k[a.share];
                if (!c && !a.renderer) throw Error("Share '" + a.share + "' is not found");
                return b.extend({
                    url: this.url,
                    text: this.text
                }, c, a)
            }, this))
        },
        _attachWindowResizeCallback: function() {
            b(a).on("resize", b.proxy(this._windowResizeHandler, this))
        },
        _detachWindowResizeCallback: function() {
            b(a).off("resize", this._windowResizeHandler)
        },
        _windowResizeHandler: function() {
            (b.isFunction(this.showLabel) || b.isFunction(this.showCount)) && (a.clearTimeout(this._resizeTimer), this._resizeTimer = setTimeout(b.proxy(this.refresh, this), this.resizeTimeout))
        },
        _render: function() {
            this._clear(), this._defineOptionsByScreen(), this._$element.addClass(this.elementClass), this._$shares = b("<div>").addClass(this.sharesClass).appendTo(this._$element), this._renderShares()
        },
        _defineOptionsByScreen: function() {
            this._screenWidth = b(a).width(), this._showLabel = g(this.showLabel, this, this._screenWidth), this._showCount = g(this.showCount, this, this._screenWidth)
        },
        _renderShares: function() {
            b.each(this.shares, b.proxy(function(a, b) {
                this._renderShare(b)
            }, this))
        },
        _renderShare: function(a) {
            var c;
            c = b.isFunction(a.renderer) ? b(a.renderer()) : this._createShare(a), c.addClass(this.shareClass).addClass(a.share ? "jssocials-share-" + a.share : "").addClass(a.css).appendTo(this._$shares)
        },
        _createShare: function(a) {
            var c = b("<div>"),
                d = this._createShareLink(a).appendTo(c);
            if (this._showCount) {
                var e = "inside" === this._showCount,
                    f = e ? d : b("<div>").addClass(this.shareCountBoxClass).appendTo(c);
                f.addClass(e ? this.shareLinkCountClass : this.shareCountBoxClass), this._renderShareCount(a, f)
            }
            return c
        },
        _createShareLink: function(a) {
            var c = this._getShareStrategy(a),
                d = c.call(a, {
                    shareUrl: this._getShareUrl(a)
                });
            return d.addClass(this.shareLinkClass).append(this._createShareLogo(a)), this._showLabel && d.append(this._createShareLabel(a)), b.each(this.on || {}, function(c, e) {
                b.isFunction(e) && d.on(c, b.proxy(e, a))
            }), d
        },
        _getShareStrategy: function(a) {
            var b = m[a.shareIn || this.shareIn];
            if (!b) throw Error("Share strategy '" + this.shareIn + "' not found");
            return b
        },
        _getShareUrl: function(a) {
            var b = g(a.shareUrl, a);
            return this._formatShareUrl(b, a)
        },
        _createShareLogo: function(a) {
            var c = a.logo,
                d = h.test(c) ? b("<img>").attr("src", a.logo) : b("<i>").addClass(c);
            return d.addClass(this.shareLogoClass), d
        },
        _createShareLabel: function(a) {
            return b("<span>").addClass(this.shareLabelClass).text(a.label)
        },
        _renderShareCount: function(a, c) {
            var d = b("<span>").addClass(this.shareCountClass);
            c.addClass(this.shareZeroCountClass).append(d), this._loadCount(a).done(b.proxy(function(a) {
                a && (c.removeClass(this.shareZeroCountClass), d.text(a))
            }, this))
        },
        _loadCount: function(a) {
            var c = b.Deferred(),
                d = this._getCountUrl(a);
            if (!d) return c.resolve(0).promise();
            var e = b.proxy(function(b) {
                c.resolve(this._getCountValue(b, a))
            }, this);
            return b.getJSON(d).done(e).fail(function() {
                b.get(d).done(e).fail(function() {
                    c.resolve(0)
                })
            }), c.promise()
        },
        _getCountUrl: function(a) {
            var b = g(a.countUrl, a);
            return this._formatShareUrl(b, a)
        },
        _getCountValue: function(a, c) {
            var d = (b.isFunction(c.getCount) ? c.getCount(a) : a) || 0;
            return "string" == typeof d ? d : this._formatNumber(d)
        },
        _formatNumber: function(a) {
            return b.each(j, function(b, c) {
                return a >= c ? (a = parseFloat((a / c).toFixed(2)) + b, !1) : void 0
            }), a
        },
        _formatShareUrl: function(b, c) {
            return b.replace(i, function(b, d, e) {
                var f = c[e] || "";
                return f ? (d || "") + a.encodeURIComponent(f) : ""
            })
        },
        _clear: function() {
            a.clearTimeout(this._resizeTimer), this._$element.empty()
        },
        _passOptionToShares: function(a, c) {
            var d = this.shares;
            b.each(["url", "text"], function(e, f) {
                f === a && b.each(d, function(b, d) {
                    d[a] = c
                })
            })
        },
        _normalizeShare: function(a) {
            return b.isNumeric(a) ? this.shares[a] : "string" == typeof a ? b.grep(this.shares, function(b) {
                return b.share === a
            })[0] : a
        },
        refresh: function() {
            this._render()
        },
        destroy: function() {
            this._clear(), this._detachWindowResizeCallback(), this._$element.removeClass(this.elementClass).removeData(f)
        },
        option: function(a, b) {
            return 1 === arguments.length ? this[a] : (this[a] = b, this._passOptionToShares(a, b), void this.refresh())
        },
        shareOption: function(a, b, c) {
            return a = this._normalizeShare(a), 2 === arguments.length ? a[b] : (a[b] = c, void this.refresh())
        }
    }, b.fn.jsSocials = function(a) {
        var e = b.makeArray(arguments),
            g = e.slice(1),
            h = this;
        return this.each(function() {
            var e, i = b(this),
                j = i.data(f);
            if (j)
                if ("string" == typeof a) {
                    if (e = j[a].apply(j, g), e !== c && e !== j) return h = e, !1
                } else j._detachWindowResizeCallback(), j._init(a), j._render();
            else new d(i, a)
        }), h
    };
    var l = function(a) {
            var c;
            b.isPlainObject(a) ? c = d.prototype : (c = k[a], a = arguments[1] || {}), b.extend(c, a)
        },
        m = {
            popup: function(c) {
                return b("<a>").attr("href", "#").on("click", function() {
                    return a.open(c.shareUrl, null, "width=600, height=400, location=0, menubar=0, resizeable=0, scrollbars=0, status=0, titlebar=0, toolbar=0"), !1
                })
            },
            blank: function(a) {
                return b("<a>").attr({
                    target: "_blank",
                    href: a.shareUrl
                })
            },
            self: function(a) {
                return b("<a>").attr({
                    target: "_self",
                    href: a.shareUrl
                })
            }
        };
    a.jsSocials = {
        Socials: d,
        shares: k,
        shareStrategies: m,
        setDefaults: l
    }
}(window, jQuery),
function(a, b, c) {
    b.extend(c.shares, {
        email: {
            label: "E-mail",
            logo: "fa fa-at",
            shareUrl: "mailto:{to}?subject={text}&body={url}",
            countUrl: "",
            shareIn: "self"
        },
        twitter: {
            label: "Tweet",
            logo: "fa fa-twitter",
            shareUrl: "https://twitter.com/share?url={url}&text={text}&via={via}&hashtags={hashtags}",
            countUrl: ""
        },
        facebook: {
            label: "Like",
            logo: "fa fa-facebook",
            shareUrl: "https://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={url}",
            countUrl: "https://graph.facebook.com/?id={url}",
            getCount: function(a) {
                return a.share && a.share.share_count || 0
            }
        },
        vkontakte: {
            label: "Like",
            logo: "fa fa-vk",
            shareUrl: "https://vk.com/share.php?url={url}&title={title}&description={text}",
            countUrl: "https://vk.com/share.php?act=count&index=1&url={url}",
            getCount: function(a) {
                return parseInt(a.slice(15, -2).split(", ")[1])
            }
        },
        googleplus: {
            label: "+1",
            logo: "fa fa-google",
            shareUrl: "https://plus.google.com/share?url={url}",
            countUrl: ""
        },
        linkedin: {
            label: "Share",
            logo: "fa fa-linkedin",
            shareUrl: "https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={url}",
            countUrl: "https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?format=jsonp&url={url}&callback=?",
            getCount: function(a) {
                return a.count
            }
        },
        pinterest: {
            label: "Pin it",
            logo: "fa fa-pinterest",
            shareUrl: "https://pinterest.com/pin/create/bookmarklet/?media={media}&url={url}&description={text}",
            countUrl: "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?&url={url}&callback=?",
            getCount: function(a) {
                return a.count
            }
        },
        stumbleupon: {
            label: "Share",
            logo: "fa fa-stumbleupon",
            shareUrl: "http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url={url}&title={title}",
            countUrl: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url={url}",
            getCount: function(a) {
                return a.result.views
            }
        },
        telegram: {
            label: "Telegram",
            logo: "fa fa-paper-plane",
            shareUrl: "tg://msg?text={url} {text}",
            countUrl: "",
            shareIn: "self"
        },
        whatsapp: {
            label: "WhatsApp",
            logo: "fa fa-whatsapp",
            shareUrl: "whatsapp://send?text={url} {text}",
            countUrl: "",
            shareIn: "self"
        },
        line: {
            label: "LINE",
            logo: "fa fa-comment",
            shareUrl: "http://line.me/R/msg/text/?{text} {url}",
            countUrl: ""
        },
        viber: {
            label: "Viber",
            logo: "fa fa-volume-control-phone",
            shareUrl: "viber://forward?text={url} {text}",
            countUrl: "",
            shareIn: "self"
        },
        pocket: {
            label: "Pocket",
            logo: "fa fa-get-pocket",
            shareUrl: "https://getpocket.com/save?url={url}&title={title}",
            countUrl: ""
        },
        messenger: {
            label: "Share",
            logo: "fa fa-commenting",
            shareUrl: "fb-messenger://share?link={url}",
            countUrl: "",
            shareIn: "self"
        }
    })
}(window, jQuery, window.jsSocials);
```

```css
.jssocials-shares {
  margin: 0.2em 0; }

.jssocials-shares * {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.jssocials-share {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0.3em 0.6em 0.3em 0; }

.jssocials-share:last-child {
  margin-right: 0; }

.jssocials-share-logo {
  width: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 1.5em; }

img.jssocials-share-logo {
  width: auto;
  height: 1em; }

.jssocials-share-link {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1; }
  .jssocials-share-link.jssocials-share-link-count {
    padding-top: .2em; }
    .jssocials-share-link.jssocials-share-link-count .jssocials-share-count {
      display: block;
      font-size: .6em;
      margin: 0 -.5em -.8em -.5em; }
  .jssocials-share-link.jssocials-share-no-count {
    padding-top: .5em; }
    .jssocials-share-link.jssocials-share-no-count .jssocials-share-count {
      height: 1em; }

.jssocials-share-label {
  padding-left: 0.3em;
  vertical-align: middle; }

.jssocials-share-count-box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0 0.3em;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: default; }
  .jssocials-share-count-box.jssocials-share-no-count {
    display: none; }

.jssocials-share-count {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle; }

.jssocials-share-twitter .jssocials-share-link {
  background: #00aced; }
  .jssocials-share-twitter .jssocials-share-link:hover {
    background: #0087ba; }

.jssocials-share-facebook .jssocials-share-link {
  background: #3b5998; }
  .jssocials-share-facebook .jssocials-share-link:hover {
    background: #2d4373; }

.jssocials-share-googleplus .jssocials-share-link {
  background: #dd4b39; }
  .jssocials-share-googleplus .jssocials-share-link:hover {
    background: #c23321; }

.jssocials-share-linkedin .jssocials-share-link {
  background: #007bb6; }
  .jssocials-share-linkedin .jssocials-share-link:hover {
    background: #005983; }

.jssocials-share-pinterest .jssocials-share-link {
  background: #cb2027; }
  .jssocials-share-pinterest .jssocials-share-link:hover {
    background: #9f191f; }

.jssocials-share-email .jssocials-share-link {
  background: #3490F3; }
  .jssocials-share-email .jssocials-share-link:hover {
    background: #0e76e6; }

.jssocials-share-stumbleupon .jssocials-share-link {
  background: #eb4823; }
  .jssocials-share-stumbleupon .jssocials-share-link:hover {
    background: #c93412; }

.jssocials-share-whatsapp .jssocials-share-link {
  background: #29a628; }
  .jssocials-share-whatsapp .jssocials-share-link:hover {
    background: #1f7d1e; }

.jssocials-share-telegram .jssocials-share-link {
  background: #2ca5e0; }
  .jssocials-share-telegram .jssocials-share-link:hover {
    background: #1c88bd; }

.jssocials-share-line .jssocials-share-link {
  background: #25af00; }
  .jssocials-share-line .jssocials-share-link:hover {
    background: #1a7c00; }

.jssocials-share-viber .jssocials-share-link {
  background: #7b519d; }
  .jssocials-share-viber .jssocials-share-link:hover {
    background: #61407b; }

.jssocials-share-pocket .jssocials-share-link {
  background: #ef4056; }
  .jssocials-share-pocket .jssocials-share-link:hover {
    background: #e9132e; }

.jssocials-share-messenger .jssocials-share-link {
  background: #0084ff; }
  .jssocials-share-messenger .jssocials-share-link:hover {
    background: #006acc; }

.jssocials-share-vkontakte .jssocials-share-link {
  background: #45668e; }
  .jssocials-share-vkontakte .jssocials-share-link:hover {
    background: #344d6c; }

.jssocials-share-link {
  padding: .5em .6em;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: background 200ms ease-in-out, border-color 200ms ease-in-out;
          transition: background 200ms ease-in-out, border-color 200ms ease-in-out; }
  .jssocials-share-link:hover, .jssocials-share-link:focus, .jssocials-share-link:active {
    color: #fff; }

.jssocials-share-count-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0 .3em;
  margin-left: 0.3em;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  -webkit-transition: background 200ms ease-in-out, border-color 200ms ease-in-out;
          transition: background 200ms ease-in-out, border-color 200ms ease-in-out; }
  .jssocials-share-count-box:hover {
    background: gainsboro; }
    .jssocials-share-count-box:hover:after {
      border-color: transparent gainsboro transparent transparent; }
  .jssocials-share-count-box:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.85em;
    left: -0.3em;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-width: 0.4em 0.4em 0.4em 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent #f5f5f5 transparent transparent;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transition: background 200ms ease-in-out, border-color 200ms ease-in-out;
            transition: background 200ms ease-in-out, border-color 200ms ease-in-out; }
  .jssocials-share-count-box .jssocials-share-count {
    line-height: 2.5em;
    color: #444; }
```

I have a problem with my site. When the site is observed on the mobile phone and is done scroll down inside a post there is a part where the site starts to scroll alone and then stops and starts shaking. I've tried a lot and I can not find a solution.

[Link of what I think is causing the problem - Desktop View](http://prntscr.com/n7kv4n)

[Link of what I think is causing the problem - Smartphone View](http://prntscr.com/n7kw4b)

I already tried to remove this section using the display: none tag and it seems that the bug no longer exists, but obviously it is of interest to have these buttons in order to share the contents.

Comment: Almost impossible to help without seeing any code ..please post some snippets of  code where you think the problem is provoked.. also please disable all plugins, and then enable all and use the default theme, to be sure that a specific theme is indeed the problem ( and not some other plugin ..

Comment: I already Updated

Answer (score 0):

you could add `html{ overflow-y: scroll;}` to see if it exposes some sort of margin error for you. It's hard to give a complete answer without being able to replicate the bug.